# Can't Read Encoded Text in Visual FoxPro DBF FIles

Tags: python, decode, dbf, visual-foxpro

I recently acquired a ton of data stored in Visual FoxPro 9.0 databases. The text I need is in Cyrillic (Russian), but of the 1000 .dbf files (complete with .fpt and .cdx files), only 4 or 5 return readable text. The rest (usually in the form of memos) returns something like this:

??9Y?u?
         yL??x??itZ?????zv?|7?g?̚?繠X6?~u?ꢴe}
?aL1?   Ş6U?|wL(Wz???8???7?@R?
                        .FAc?TY?H???#f U???K???F&?w3A??hEڅԦX?MiOK?,?AZ&GtT??u??r:?q???%,NCGo0??H?5d??]?????O{??
                               z|??\??pq?ݑ?,??om???K*???lb?5?D?J+z!??
                                                                     ?G>j=???N ?H?jѺAs`c?HK\i
??9a*q??

For the life of me, I can't figure out how this is encoded. I have tried all kinds of online decoders, opened up the .dbfs in many database programs, and used Python to open and manipulate them. All of them returns the similar messiness as above, but never readable Russian.

Note: I know that these databases are not corrupt, because they came accompanied by enterprise software that can open, query and read them successfully. However, that software will not export the data, so I am left working directly with the .dbfs.

Happy to share an example .dbf if would help get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect if it is *FoxPro* database, that the Russian there is encoded in some pre-Unicode encoding for Russian as for most Eastern European languages in ancient times.

For example: [Windows-1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) or [ISO 8859-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-5).

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

- the encoding has not been correctly stored in the dbf file
- the dbf file has been encrypted

If it's been encrypted I can't help you.  If it's a matter of finding the correct encoding, [my dbf package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) may be of use.  Feel free to send me a sample dbf file if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi Ethan, did you get to inspect a sample file? Was there any further movement on solving this problem?

Comment: @JohnMachin:  After 3.5 years, a few SO people helped, and no name attached to `user2520638`... well, I do not remember if there was further interaction with this specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

'?' characters don't convey much.  Try looking at the contents of the memo fields as hex, and see whether what you're seeing looks anything like text in any encodings.  (Apologies if you've tried this using Python already).  Of course if it is actually encrypted you may be out of luck unless you can find out the key and method.